# iOS Duplicate Symbol

Tags: ios, cocoapods, reachability, mobile-app-tracker

I've looked into the Pods and all the fixes for this duplicate symbol to no end.  I get this error when using the MobileAppTracker in Pods and then using the Reachability.h.  Funny thing is it builds fine on my machine but when it builds in Jenkins machine I get this...

```
duplicate symbol _kReachabilityChangedNotification in:
    /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iPhone/workspace/Pods/MobileAppTracker/libMobileAppTracker-3.4.a(MATReachability.o)
    /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/iPhone/workspace/build/libPods.a(Reachability.o)
```

Funny thing is that there is no MATReachability file in the MobileAppTracker lib.  Both Reachability and MobileAppTracker are in Pods.

All these solutions do not work:

1. [Reachability duplicate symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11028824/346309)
2. [How to access to Reachability in MKNetworkKit-iOS or avoid duplicate symbols with own added Reachability?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22351264/346309)
3. [duplicate symbol linker error due to libWeANDSFLibrary.a(ASIReachability.o)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22451795/346309)

Comment: They possibly both declare global constants `_kReachabilityChangedNotification` do a project find for that and include the pods in the search.

Comment: Apparently its in the libMobileAppTracker Pods\Headers\Reachability\Reachability.h(59): extern NSString *const kReachabilityChangedNotification;
Pods\MobileAppTracker\libMobileAppTracker-3.4.a(17008): Pods\Reachability\Reachability.h(59): extern NSString *const kReachabilityChangedNotification;

Comment: If you have the code files you may be able to change the name of it. Maybe prefix it with `MAT` so that it doesn't clash. Or just don't use MAT.

Comment: No they are Pods and MATReachability is inside the *.a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was fixed today with a MobileAppTracker update. https://github.com/MobileAppTracking/cocoapod/issues/3